# No spacing between words in the pseudocode package

Tags: spacing, pseudocode

I am using the `pseudocode` package for an algorithm. (Here is the documentation: [Pseudo Code Package Documentation](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pseudocode/pseudocode.pdf))

There is no spacing between normal text inside the pseudocode block. I have to manually insert `\` after every word for spacing.

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{pseudocode}
\begin{document}
    This is a text area. Another text\\

\begin{pseudocode}{Celsius To Fahrenheit}{c}
f \GETS {9c/5} + 32\\
\RETURN{f}\\
\\

\BEGIN
 basic\ algo\ for\ nothing\\
 secondary\ algo
\END
\\\\

This\ is\ experimental\ text 
\\\\


\end{pseudocode}

Outside Pseudocode

\begin{pseudocode}{Name}{Parameter 1, 2 ,3}

\IF True
\THEN 
\BEGIN
    something\ to\ do\\
    or\ ther\ thing\ to\ do
\END
\ELSEIF otherwise
\THEN
\BEGIN
    Do\ other\ things\\
    Don't\ do\ something\ else
\END
\\

\FOR i \GETS 0 \TO 10
\DO something\ processing
\\

\WHILE not\ true \DO don't\ do\ it
\\\\

\REPEAT something 
\UNTIL exception
\\\\

\PROCEDURE{Procedure name}{proc\ params}
    something
\ENDPROCEDURE

\DO \BEGIN
1.something\\
2.anything\\
3.nothing\\
4.many\ things\\
5.everything
\END
\\

\REPEAT repeat something
\UNTIL some condition is met


\end{pseudocode}

\end{document}
```

But, according to the documentation it should automatically insert space between words in text. Please help, is there anyway to activate spacing? or any other having these problem? I really liked the output of this package.

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I have update the code, this time gave latex compilable full code. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Inside the `\BEGIN\ENd` blocks, the text is set in mathmode. You will have to use a `\COMMENT` instead or you wrap your text in `\text{}` from `mathtools`(`amsmath`). Maybe you should have a look on other pseudo-code packages as this does not seem to be the right one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual also says

> Note that the contents of
>   statements are typeset in math mode. Therefore, non-math mode text must
>   be enclosed in an `\mbox{}`.

By using `\mbox` or `\text` (requires `amsmath`) for the text parts, it works. The manual is a bit wrong in the first examples actually, here is a code excerpt from `pseudocode.tex`, used to create the manual:

```
To form compound statements from simple statements, the {\em begin-end} 
construct is used as follows:
\begin{verbatim}
 \BEGIN
    some statement\\
    another statement\\
    yet another statement
 \END
\end{verbatim}
This generates the following:

\medskip
\begin{pseudocode}[display]{}{}
\BEGIN
\mbox{some statement}\\
\mbox{another statement}\\
\mbox{yet another statement}
\END
\end{pseudocode}
```

The first code will not create the output shown right after, as that uses `\mbox`, whereas the code example does not. Below is an example for your original code, where I've used both `\text` and `\mbox`. Stick to just one of them though. Consider also the `\COMMENT` macro that LaRiFaRi mentioned in a comment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pseudocode,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{pseudocode}{Name}{Parameter 1, 2 ,3}
\COMMENT{This is experimental text} \\

\IF \mbox{using \texttt{mbox}}
\THEN 
\BEGIN
    \mbox{something to do}\\
    \mbox{or other thing to do}
\END
\ELSEIF \text{using \texttt{text}}
\THEN
\BEGIN
    \text{Do  other things}\\
    \text{Don't do something else}
\END
\end{pseudocode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for elaborative example, you just saved my day.